# Westend/Westmint: Difficulty in Minting a Fungible Asset in Westmint

Tags: westend

Someone sent me `$WND tokens` from faucet but I did not receive it.

[image]

[image]

Also, why do you have 1 !drip request quota on your faucet? I find it hard to test with all this blockers you set in place. They're slowing me down. This is so anticlimactic.

I want to `mint` some meme coins on `Westmint` which I'll later implement on `Polkadot`. I can't do it because you make it hard for testers to do so. I can't get `$WND tokens!`

Can you please send me `50 $WND`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some research I found your address:
https://westend.subscan.io/account/5EfFtggHCobGTgfS7FuAvnyuZfZhX2RDc2TbgMSGfPqPebdX

So you did get 2x 1 WND. WND are tokens for the `Westend` network. This is a **test** network.

I toped you up 50 WND. You can see the tx here: https://westend.subscan.io/account/5EfFtggHCobGTgfS7FuAvnyuZfZhX2RDc2TbgMSGfPqPebdX

Those tokens are only credited to your account on the Westend network and **not** on the Polkadot network.

While you could reuse an address on several networks, this is not recommended. Many clients do some magic to make it work seamlessly but tokens remains on their chain and the Westend faucet will not send any token on the Polkadot network.

I see you use Talisman. Make sure to enabled testnets:
[image]

then ensure you pick the right chain:
[image]

finally select the account you want to use.

Comment: Thank you serr. This was really helpful. Apologies for my attitude, I was so frustrated. I can now see my $WND tokens. Thank you for sending me 50, wow! :D

Comment: No worries. Your frustration is understandable. We are all chill, so feel free to ask. Note that anyone with either a parity matrix account or a web3 one, will be able to send WND very easily so that should never take long. Please do return the remaining funds if you no longer need them.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, why do you have 1 !drip request quota on your faucet?

This is to prevent hoarding and attacks against the network.

> I find it hard to test with all this blockers you set in place.
> They're slowing me down.
> This is so anticlimactic.

You can test a lot with a few WND. Note that you can drip the faucet daily.

> I want to mint some meme coins on Westmint which I'll later implement on Polkadot. I can't do it because you make it hard for testers to do so. I can't get $WND tokens!

Yes, you can request that and you will get them.

> Can you send me 50 $WND pls?

Sure but for that you'd need to provide an address!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 open issues which might solve your problem
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-testnet-faucet/issues/152
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-testnet-faucet/issues/151

The westend faucet drips tokens only to westend relay-chain, not to westmint for now

Comment: hey Mak thanks for helping me earlier. Appreciate it.