# How to Transfer $WND Tokens from Westend going to Westmint to MINT Fungible Token?

Tags: westend

Thank you to the community who initially answered my question [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/westend-westmint-difficulty-in-minting-a-fungible-asset-in-westmint)

So this is where I'm at, I have 52 $WND tokens in Westend:
[image]

But the minting center for NFTs is at Westmint, which is sitting on Westend relay chain.
So ofc, I go to Westmint. But I go there and I see I have no $WND tokens, which is what's needed to pay my custom NFT Fungible asset.

[image]

So, again, I'm stuck and faced with impediment.

Can you please help me how to resolve this? What step am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There **used to** be a **teleport** item in the menu under `Accounts` or `Network` if I recall but I see this is no longer there. But worry not, there is a way :)

You will need to craft an extrinsic from the `Developer`/`Extrinsics` Menu.

To get start started, I created a [template transaction for you](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fwestend-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode/0x630103000100a10f030001010096d522d22a25ff4b30146d13e274a6c940be96f191e3e13b524d9040c6bdd4190304000000000b00a0724e180900000000)

Clicking on that link will open PolkadotJS and show you a transaction you can edit as shown below:
[image]

First click the `Submission` button/tab so you can edit the tx:
[image]

Make sure to send the tx from an account of yours that has enough funds.
Here is a screenshot of the XCM call, it shows the relevant information:
[image]

Here are a few caveats:

- select an account of yours
- your account should have enough funds
- provide the right parachain ID, westmint is `1000`
- the fungible amount is in units, so 10 WND = 10_000_000_000_000 (+ 12 zeroes)
- make sure the `feeAssetItem` is `0`

Note that upon transaction success, you will need to wait a few more seconds (usually less than 12s) on the parachain for your WND to show up on Westmint.

See you on the other side :) and have fun.